# Cannot Throw New Exception Class

Tags: java, exception

Program should read the file, adds the value, and produce an average. However, in the case there's an error caused by wrong data type (e.g. "23 24 82 f 13 5"), It should use try and catch to prevent the program from crashing and display the user a message like, "Error! Wrong data type found in file. System reads: f." I tried looking up on YouTube on this particular problem, along with copying the exact way I did on last assignment. I don't really know the keyword for this problem, so no luck for now.

Below is the code in one of my class:

```
/**Method to sum numbers inside file with exception in case the system reads something other than numerical value*/
public double  getSum() {
    try{
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            sum = sum + sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Sum is: " + sum);
        }

    }catch(IllegalDataRead e) {
        throw new IllegalDataRead("Can't add value! System reads: ", sc.nextByte());
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Below will be the constructor for the custom exception class:

```
/**Constructor for wrong data type read*/
public IllegalDataRead(String message, byte b) {
    super(message + " " + b);
}
```

Here's my console:

Enter the file name or directory where the file is located: Numbers.txt
Sum is: 34.0Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException:  Can't add value!
    at lab05.Number.getSum(Number.java:34)
    at lab05.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:23)
Sum is: 68.0Sum is: 122.0Sum is: 136.0Sum is: 168.0Sum is: 192.0

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking—how to tell if the read data is invalid?

Comment: You didn't show the code for `IllegalDataRead`, or your error message. If you're getting "can't throw", that suggests that `IllegalDataRead` isn't an `Exception`. (Additionally, you want to catch something else, and reading more data _in the catch block_ doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: @DaveNewton If it reads something other than number.
@chrylis-onstrike- I'm sorry. I just edited it to include the error message. I believe the constructor for `IllegalDataRead` is up there as well. The `IllegalDataRead` extends to the `Exception` class. I'm new, so my wording may be still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All of the values appear to be integers, so I would suggest using `int` (instead of `double`). Use `Scanner.hasNextInt()` before trying to consume the next `int` value, and remember to consume anything that isn't an `int`. I would not `print` anything about the running sum in `getSum()` - separate concerns. Something like,

```
private static final String _MSG = "Error! Wrong data type found in file. "
        + "System reads: %s.%n";
public int getSum() {
    int sum = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += sc.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.err.printf(msg, sc.next());
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If it should support floating point then use `hasNextDouble()` like

```
public double getSum() {
    double sum = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            sum += sc.nextDouble();
        } else {
            System.err.printf(msg, sc.next());
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: The thing is, this is the instruction I got: "Submit print-out of source code + output showing valid numbers in the file and also invalid numbers in the file." **Edit** I will try your suggestion. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @TriparadoxClifford Your requirement is for a [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))? Oh boy!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Lol... English is so ambiguous.